# passing null as aparameter to listOf

Tags: kotlin, kotlin-android-extensions

can you please tell me what does the second parameter passed to the method listOf means? why do we need to pass null? why is the purpose of it?

**code**:

```
val listWithNulls: List<String?> = listOf("Kotlin", null)
```

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[`listOf`](https://kotlinlang.org/api/latest/jvm/stdlib/kotlin.collections/list-of.html) accepts a `vararg` of elements. Your second `null` is just one of many elements you passed to the list. Your list then consists of `"Kotlin"` and `null`.

So to answer your other questions:

- why do we need to pass null? you don't *need* to...
- what is the purpose of it? the person who wrote that code wanted to add a `null` element to the list... if it isn't clear from the context, why it is there, you should better ask the one who wrote that code. If it just consists of the line you showed, it's probably to demonstrate how lists with a nullable type can be constructed/used.